# How to sort file with modified date?

Tags: java, android

i am trying to get list of files in a dir in a array sort with modified date. Here is the code i am using for it

```
public static void sortFilesByLastModifiedDate(ArrayList<String> myfiles) {
     String[] myfile = new String[myfiles.size()];
     myfile = myfiles.toArray(myfile);

     Comparator<File> comparator = new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
                    return Long.valueOf(o1.lastModified()).
                            compareTo(o2.lastModified());
            }
        };
        Arrays.sort(myfile, comparator);

    }
```

`Arrays.sort(myfile, comparator);` console shows error in this code 
The method `sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>)` in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments `(String[], Comparator<File>)`

please suggest how to solve this?

Comment: Can you please tell us what error is given by the `sort()`?

Comment: `myFile` is a String array and you are trying to sort it with a `File` comparator.

Comment: try Collections.sort(list, comparator), no need convert list to array

Answer (score 2):

Either change your list to contain `File` objects or change your comparator to operate on `String` objects.

I would recommend the former option. This allows you to establish the files exist before passing them into the comparator. Note that [`File.lastModified()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29) returns `0` if the file does not exists (which might be unexpected).

*As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570453/how-to-sort-file-with-modified-date/17570534#comment25563279_17570453), you can sort a list using `Collections.sort()` so you have no need to convert to an array.*

Answer (score 0):

It means you cannot compare File and String objects.
Instead of this you can compare String and String like:

```
Arrays.sort(myfile,new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
            //todo: finish here.
            return Long.valueOf(new File(lhs).lastModified()).compareTo(new File(rhs).lastModified());                  
        }
    });
```

I think you can try to use Filenames instead of directly the File Object.
And in "compare" you load your 2 files to be compared internally, and managing errors (like IOException).

Comment: Your example will compare the files lexicographically, which is confusing (and incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to sort the files according to date modified.

```
private ArrayList<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
        ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator() {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

                if (((File)o1).lastModified() > ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (((File)o1).lastModified() < ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
                    return +1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }

        });

if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {

                    if (!inFiles.contains(file))
                        inFiles.add(file);
                }

        }

        return inFiles;
    }
```